# Canvas element does not display properly on Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I'm using canvas to display stages of a story based on a character the user creates. The canvas loads up the background and then renders the user-created character ontop of it. The following is my function used to draw the canvas element (I'm using react). It works perfectly fine on chrome but does not display the character on firefox. I've checked to make sure that the API gives all the proper responses so it's not an issue with the image requests.

This is the function I wrote that loads the images then renders the canvas element:

```
            const can0 = document.getElementById(props.id)
            const ctx0 = can0.getContext('2d', false)

            const bg = new Image()
            let bgLoaded = false
            const char = new Image()
            let charLoaded = false

            bg.src = 'http://localhost:4000/story/' + props.getStage + '/' + props.bg
            bg.onload = () => {
                bgLoaded = true
                can0.height = bg.height
                can0.width = bg.width
                if (charLoaded) {
                    ctx0.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, can0.width, can0.height)
                    ctx0.drawImage(char, can0.width / 2.5, can0.height / 2.2, char.width * 12, char.height * 12.1)
                }
            }
            char.src =
                'http://localhost:4000/character/' +
                con.getChar.gender +
                '/shihtzu/' +
                con.getChar.color +
                '/' +
                props.pose
            char.onload = () => {
                charLoaded = true
                if (bgLoaded) {
                    ctx0.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, can0.width, can0.height)
                    ctx0.drawImage(char, can0.width / 2.5, can0.height / 2.2, char.width * 12, char.height * 12.1)
                }
            }
```

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong in there.  You don't have any error message? You can add logs at every steps and check which one didn't fire.

Comment: @Kaiido, I've added logs everywhere and it seems that they all fire up. Could it be that this is just an issue with firefox support for canvas?

Comment: No, Firefox supports canvas fully, What about the canvas? It's rendered but transparent? Is there any CSS applied to it? Can you extract every parts of your setup in small modules and check from where ot starts failing?

Comment: @kaiido there isn't any css applied directly to the canvas other than a border property, removing it doesn't change anything. What's confusing me is that it works perfectly fine on chrome and edge. With Firefox the canvas element itself also displays properly, but the image stored in the variable char does not get rendered.

Comment: And what type of image is it? If svg, does it have a width and height property set to px?

Comment: The char image is SVG, I think that's the issue, I will check it as soon as I get home, thank you!